# vim - how do I set a shortcut?

Tags: vim, neocomplete

I'm trying to follow the instructions for configuring NeoComplete

The config example is this:

```
inoremap <expr><C-l>     neocomplete#complete_common_string()
```

I'm assuming this means, press Ctrl-L to accept the first completion. It doesn't work.

Can someone explain the `<expr><C-l>` bit?

Answer (score 0):

if you used `<expr>` mapping, it means, the string returned by given expression will be `{rhs}` mapping.

E.g. you have a function return a string `abc`, then with  `nnoremap <expr>`, your mapping will do same in normal mode pressing `abc`

Comment: So what does this mean I should press in normal mode to activate the shortcut? Will it work just the same in Insert mode?

Comment: @cjm2671 it means, your function returns the real keystrokes, I don't know what does the `neo.....()` function returns, if it returns completion list, you should not use it in `<expr>` mapping.